# How can I add space around the first/last bars in my seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am building a barplot using seaborn and have most of the items addressed. But I'm running into an issue with the first and last items in the plot. In the attached screenshot you can see that the first and last bar are at the edge of the figure when I want there to be space between the edge and bar.

[image: bar graph]

Here is the code that is creating the graph

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17,10))



# variables for table
examiner_figure_title = (f'Examiner Production - {yesterday}')


# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.suptitle(examiner_figure_title, fontsize=24)

# variables for bar graph
x = yesterday_df['Production']
y = yesterday_df['Examiner']
    

ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, hue=y, orient='h', ax=ax, palette=sns.color_palette())
ax.set(yticklabels=[])
ax.tick_params(left=False)
ax.bar_label
        
# change_width(ax, .75)
change_height(ax, 1)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5))
plt.show()
```

I've tried changing my figure size, thinking that might have been the cause. That did not impact the bar location.

I am using a custom height function to create bars rather than thin lines. If I don't apply the custom size of the bars the lines are not against the figure edge but you can't really see the lines, which is why I am using the custom setting. Perhaps I need to add something to the function? (attaching both the custom height and width for view)

```
def change_width(ax, new_value):
    for patch in ax.patches:
        current_width = patch.get_width()
        diff = current_width - new_value
        
        patch.set_width(new_value)
        
        patch.set_x(patch.get_x() + diff * .5)

def change_height(ax, new_value):
    for patch in ax.patches:
        current_height = patch.get_height()
        diff = current_height - new_value
        
        patch.set_height(new_value)
        
        patch.set_y(patch.get_y() + diff * .5)
```

Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Comment: You probably want to use `sns.barplot(...., dodge=False)`. Otherwise, a spot is reserved for each of the hue-values for each of the y-positions.  If you really need to resize the bars, you can use `ax.relim(); ax.autoscale_view()` to recalculate the y limits.  Maybe you want to combine that with `ax.margins(y=0.01)` as the default margins are quite large.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Just using dodge=False created the space around the bars and meant I did not need to use the formula to change the bar size

Comment: To use `ax.bar_label` here, `for bars_group in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(bars_group, padding=2)`.  Maybe together with `ax.margins(x=0.15)`  to have more space for the texts.

Comment: If you set  `bbox_to_anchor=` for the legend, you also need to set `loc=`, e.g. `loc='center left'`.  By default, `loc='best'` is used, which can change depending on the plot contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recalculate the limits after changing the rectangles, you could use:

```py
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.margins(y=0.01)  # for a smaller padding, as the default is rather wide
```

But probably you just want to set `dodge=False`. Otherwise, a spot is reserved for each of the hue-values for each of the y-positions.

Some other remarks:

- the default `sns.color_palette()` only has 10 different colors, which makes the legend confusing; you could use e.g. `turbo` or `tab20` for more colors
- to add bar labels, you can loop through `ax.containers` e.g. : `for bars_group in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(bars_group)` (there is one "group" per hue value)
- if you set `bbox_to_anchor=` for the legend, you also need to set `loc=`; by default, loc='best' is used, which can change depending on the plot contents

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 10))
fig.patch.set_visible(False)

x = [1, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 19, 20, 23, 24, 27, 28, 31, 32, 35.5, 40, 39, 40]
y = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Berylium', 'Boron', 'Carbon', 'Nitrogen', 'Oxygen', 'Fluorine', 'Neon', 'Sodium', 'Magnesium', 'Aluminium', 'Silicon', 'Phosphorus', 'Sulphur', 'Chlorine', 'Argon', 'Potassium', 'Calcium']

ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, hue=y, orient='h', dodge=False, ax=ax, palette='turbo')
ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False)
for bars_group in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bars_group, padding=3, fontsize=15)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5), loc='center left')
# ax.margins(x=0.15) # optionally more space for the text
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with dodge=False]

Comment: Thanks for the color tip. I used Dodge=False to get the space I wanted without having to resize the bars